# find -exec throws error even with ending plus ('+') sign

Tags: find

So I am aware that we have to end `find -exec`  commands with `;` or `+`, but I cannot fathom why is this not working:

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp3" -exec mv {} . +
```

when this is working

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp3" -exec mv {} . \;
```

My first suspect is the plus sign is might have been unescaped, but `\+` doesn't work either. Then I thought that `mv` might have interpreted `+` for something else, but I couldn't figure out how to work around it. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is this error?

Comment: Well, at a guess, [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/179346/73093) - not a duplicate.

Comment: This is documented in the `find` manual for the `-exec` option, but unfortunately not clearly enough in the GNU `find` manual.